# ActiveRecord join with new 1.9 hash syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an AR query that looks like this

```
user.books.joins(:authors).where(:authors => {:id => [1,2,3]}, :title => 'blah')
```

This is just an example but notice when I specify conditions on the joined table I'm using the pre-1.9 hash syntax. ie. `:authors => {:id => [1,2,3]}`

Is there a way to do this same query with the 1.9 hash syntax?

It's pretty readable as it is and using the 1.9 syntax will probably make it less so. But I'm still curious if it's possible and what it would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should perfectly with the the new syntax:

```
user.books.joins(:authors).where(authors: {id: [1,2,3]}, title: 'blah')
```

Comment: I think it's worth to note that the first `authors` is the **association** name and the second one is the **table** name. So if it was a 1-to-1 association, the first one would be singular and the second one would be plural.